# for those who worked with skia, how would i build a skia program?

Tags: c++, chromium, ninja, skia, gn

i recently have finished building the skia library on my windows 10 machine, however im honestly pretty confused as to how i would even go about using this library in any program. as the documentation provides little to no guidance on using the library with an actual program outside of just compiling the HelloWorld program in the examples. im incredibly lost here, and have no idea where i could even begin

im new to C++ and i have never really used libraries before. a really clear guide on how to compile a simple c++ program with the library would be very helpful.

Comment: I would advise starting with something easier, honestly.  This is akin to someone saying "I have just started riding a bicycle.  How do I do a double back flip jump?"  Learn how to use libraries and get programs working with simpler libraries first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.